# For every probability $\mu$ on $(\Bbb R,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R))$ exists at least a real r.v. $X$ s.t. $P^X=\mu$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a probability $\mu$ on $(\Bbb R,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R))$, does exist always some random real-valued variable $X$ (defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$) such that its distribution $P^X$ be the same probability on $(\Bbb R,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R))$ as $\mu$?

I think yes, and I think this should be a general result, but I never read it anywhere!

Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/probability-and-stochastic/9781118593134/9781118593134c02a.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: "yes".

Take $\Omega=\mathbb R$, $\mathcal A=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $P=\mu$.

For $X$ you can take the identity prescribed by $\omega\mapsto\omega$.

Blandness and elegance hand in hand.

Comment: Ok thanks man! Ah: would you laugh? I just found a notebook on which -months ago- I obtained this result! Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I dare to say that you will "a.s." not forget this result anymore. Of course with an accent on "almost". After all you are human, just like me.